# How can I save a 3d array in a SQL table

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server

I'm writing  code in C#.
It has two type of user: distributors and clients.

Clients can see all products of all distributors and can select them with mentioning the number of each product they need.So they make a list of orders.
Distributors can see lists of orders received from all clients to them. The table should contains "distributor id" and "client id" and "list of ordered products" with their cost and numbers which have ordered.
But I have no idea about saving this data to a single table.i want that each row mentions to a single list of orders from a special client to a special distributor.

Can I have a 3D table or an array or there is a better and more efficient way?

Comment: Can you update your post with an Entity Relationship Diagram so we can see how things relate together?

Comment: Having all your data in one table seems always a bad idea. Normalizing your model is advisable.

Comment: Assume you would want to store values in 3D space. So at the coordinates `x = 1; y = 2; z = 3;` you want to store the value `42`. If you had a table with columns x, y, z and value, you could easily insert the above example as values `(1, 2, 3, 42)`. -- Now if someone wants to see all values, where `y` is `2` you can get that. Or the sum of all values where `x` is `1`. -- Or all the values where `x` is `1` and `z` is in `(3, 35, 256)`.

Comment: Substitute `x` with `client id`, `y` with `distributor id`, `z` with `product id` and `value` with whatever kind of information to store at that place in 3D space (can very well be several columns, whatever you need).

Comment: There is insufficient information posted for anybody to be able to provide a reasonable answer here. It is so vague what you are trying to do all anybody can do is guess.

Comment: @SeanLange I have updated my question. is it still unclear?

Comment: Find a tutorial on relational databases. It's what they do.

Comment: Ummm.....no. All you did was change a few words to other words.

Comment: @ilia7 - "I'm writing a code in c#." -- why don't you start with providing us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of that code? (rough class structure; and with an example of what you mean by "factor").

Comment: `i want that each row mentions to a single list` For a good database design, you shouldn't be storing an entire list in a single row. It's not impossible from a technical perspective (e.g. a string with comma-separated values), but your expectations preclude a good answer and seem unnecessarily restrictive in that regard.

Comment: @Flater thanks a lot. so do you think it's better that i store each single product order into a row ?

Comment: @ilia7: Yes. The data format is much easier to work with, and it still allows you to e.g. generate a list (based on the existing rows) if you need one at some point in the future (e.g. when you want to print an invoice).

Comment: @Flater thank you. Regards <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you give, it seems you want a data model like this:

```
Distributor
 Id
 Name

Client
 Id 
 Name

Product
 Id
 DistributorId (foreign key)

Order
 Id
 ProductId (foreign key)     
 ClientId (foreign key)
 Number
```

That way you can store product orders from clients, and make sure distributors see order of their own products by selecting all orders having productId's that are linked to the selected distributor.

Comment: thanks a lot. but i want to store each factors in a row of the table.

Comment: @ilia7 what do you mean by a "factor"? An ordered product? That would be a single record in the `Order` table.

Comment: i mean a list of ordered products

Comment: You do _not_ want to save a list of orders into one record, believe me.

Comment: so what should i do? save each product order in a row?

Comment: @oerkelens - Maybe you want an `Order` class with just `Id` and `ClientId` (and maybe an `OrderDate` and other head information) and as a second class an `OrderPosition` (or similar) with `Id, OrderId (foreign key), ProductId (foreign key), Quantity, Price` and whatever else is needed on a position-base.

Comment: Does your solution not imply that if I order two products from the same distributor, that this then counts as two separate orders? I think you need an extra step inbetween, e.g. Order > OrderLine so that a list of products can be considered as a single order (and my two products each have an OrderLine that both refer to the same Order)

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to do what you want?  Yes.

Should you?  No.

I mean, let's say you set up your table.  A column for the distributor, a column for the client, and a column for your list of orders (let's use XML for the example) :

```
DistID  ClientID  Orders
1       1         <item>A</item><item>B</item><item>C</item>
2       1         <item>D</item><item>C</item>
2       2         <item>E</item><item>A</item><item>F</item><item>G</item>
```

... so what problems will you run into?  First, imagine trying to add or remove an order.  You'd have to read the full Orders list, change it, and then write it all back to SQL.  That's a lot of overhead, especially if your 'list' has a lot of items or if you're doing a lot of order adds/removes.

Worse, what happens when you need to find anyone that's ordered 'B'?  You're going to have to do a full text scan on that column - no index seeks, no optimizations, nothing - just to find the matching items.

Here's my suggestion - take a look at "**SQL Normalization**" - basically, the guidelines on how to organize SQL data efficiently and effectively.  Here are some good starter places:

http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html